# Reverse Engineering / Log or intercept program instructions

Tags: reverse-engineering, intercept, cnc

I'm trying to find a way of replicating the action / instruction that a physical button being pushed on a control panel sends to the software of a CNC machine of ours.

Ultimately I would like to integrate this instruction into an executable file I could make using AutoIT, but that is further down the line!

After some googling, resulting in all kinds of weird and wonderful results, I'm at a loss of how to begin this task. I believe I need to either use debugging software to find the instruction as it takes place, or possibly Process Monitor?

The machine runs off of a Windows XP machine.

Unfortunately obtaining this information from the manufacturer is not an option.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction that would be appreciated,

Thanks

Edit: I have since come across Windows Hooks, Detours and Interception, but still haven't made much progress!

Answer (score 0):

Your topic is too broad ... You might as well be asking "How do I reverse engineer?" First thing I would do would be to load up the program in a debugger, put a breakpoint in the callback function and find out what the button is doing. What you will most likely find is that it's pushing some information onto the stack and making a call to an external .DLL such as an API or device driver ( you could probably find out which DLL using Process Monitor too ). Just load that .DLL up into your new program and make the same call.